# Is $f$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, notation

Exercise 11.21 in Real Analysis for... by Richard Bass says: 
Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n : \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, $c>0$, and $p<n$? If $|f(x)| \leq c|x|^{-p} \chi_{B(0,1)}(x)$ a.e, prove that $f$ is integrable.

First of all, am I right to assume that $|x|$ means $||x||$?

In what follows, I will choose $||\cdot|| = || \cdot ||_1$

To get some intuition, I tried the case where $n=2$ and $p=1$.

We have that:

$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} |f(x)| \, dm(x) \leq c\int_{B(0,1)} ||x||_1 dm(x) = c\int_{-1}^{1} [ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{|x_1| + |x_2|}dm(x_1)]\, dm(x_2)$

and

$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{|x_1| + |x_2|}dm(x_1) \leq \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{|x_1|}dm(x_1)=2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x_1} dm(x_1)$

But $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x_1} dm(x_1)$ is not finite.

So, even in the easiest case I am kind of stuck.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Quite likely it's the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anwer to your previous question :

Yes. $|\cdot|$ is used sometimes to avoid the heaviness of $||\cdot ||$.

Plus, remember that all norms are equivalent on $\mathbb R^n$, so (in this case) you do not really care which one it is !

(Partial) answer to the new one :

Your estimation is far too braod : $\frac{1}{|x|+|y|}$ is integrable for $x$ between $-1$ and $+1$, except when $y = 0$. So you should not estimate this by using the case $y=0$, and on the contrary integrate this away from the line $y = 0$ (which is negligible). Then you find an integrable function of $y$.

Comment: The truth of "you do not really care which one it is !" depends a lot on what you're actually doing. So while it may apply here, it should be stated with qualifications.

Comment: @Masacroso It answered the question 30 minutes ago. Then the question post tripled in length.

Comment: I am sorry Arthur, I hesitated to make a new post but then decided just to edit it.

Comment: But since I use Fubini $y$ is a constant and am only interested in bounding the function with respect to $x$ no ? 
I kind of see what you're saying though but can't seem to make it rigorous...

Comment: To use Fubini, you need to estimate the function $y \longmapsto \int f(x,y) dx$, and show that it is an integrable function of $y$. What I am proposing is to bound this not by a constant function of $y$ (which is not possible), but to calculate this function, which is not defined for $y=0$ but is defined elsewhere.